# Media files not bing displayed

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

Ive been studying django and from what I've read MEDIA and STATIC should be kept seperate so I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media_cdn')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

    # Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
        os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media'),
    )
```

I have the ability to create post from my site and when I develop locally the url is this

```
/media/None/earthquake.png
```

from this

```
{{post.image.url}}
```

and I use it like this

```
<img src='{{post.image.url}}>
```

to display the image

The docs I read I'm not using static to get the picture.

this is my post model

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "{}/{}".format(instance.id, filename)


class Post(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('draft', 'Draft'),
       ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                            unique_for_date='publish')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,
                              height_field='height_field',
                              width_field='width_field')
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                              choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                              default='draft')
    video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True,)
```

I'm following a tutorial and I think the upload_location function might be the issue although I could be wrong. How can I make my images show in production? I have whitenoise installed but in the docs it says to serve my images like this

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

so I tried this

```
 <img src="{% static 'None/car.jpg' %}" alt="Hi!"  width="100" height="100"/>
```

this is my file structure

[image]

How do I show my image in production

also The examples don't show how to dynamically display images. Each of my post willhave their own pictures. This does not work

```
<img src="{% static '{{post.image.url'%}" alt="Hi!"  width="100" height="100"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to store and serve user-uploaded media in this way on Heroku. Instead of storing media locally on disk you will need to store it on a backing service like Amazon S3. Have a look at the [Django Storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package which provides storage backends for many different services.

Comment: Is this just a heroku thing? Or are all host the same? And what about whitenoise

Comment: and another thing. Without doing anything extra. I was able to display my images on heroku. Then all of a sudden after waking my app up the most recent image wasnt showing. Then later on all my images were broken. Strange

Comment: It's an issue that affects almost all Platform-as-a-Service providers like Heroku. There are other ways of hosting your application which would give you a persistent local filesystem but they wouldn't be as easy to manage and scale as Heroku is.

Comment: The reason it would have appeared to work is because Heroku gives you an [Ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which allows you to store temporary files but they won't persist between restarts and won't be shared between instances of your application.

Comment: so I have to also pay to host images on Amazon just to display images. Just when I thought I could deploy, It pulls me back in!